# How to include font to clickOnce installation

Tags: fonts, clickonce

Is there any way to include font to a clickOnce installation of a winforms application in visual studio. The program that we are developing requires a font that is not installed in windows by default.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this in the future: There is a similar topic with more up-to-date and better answers regarding this issue- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007805/embedding-deploying-custom-font-in-net-app/3008351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the font into a res file and have it loaded without being installed to the computer.

See:

- [MS: Packaging fonts with applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications)
- [Bob Powell: Embed Fonts](http://web.archive.org/web/20090211154611/http://www.bobpowell.net/embedfonts.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't help since we need to actually install the font on the computer.

Comment: then perhaps you can p/invoke the function add font resource to install it if your program finds it missing.  see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.AddFontResource

Comment: This is exactly why link only answers are bad things.

Comment: @RubberDuck, you must be looking at the 4.5 page.  Just select the [4.0 version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303(v=vs.100).aspx).  The target page is quite long, and the summary is to "include the font in a resource file, and load it from there".

Comment: Or you could add relevant information here in your answer and fix the links @Mitch.

Answer (score 2):

Can you create a setup & deployment project to install the font, and deploy it as a prerequisite to the ClickOnce application. You can turn it into a custom prerequisite by using the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator to create the prerequisite package, copy into the VS packages folder, and it will show up in Visual Studio as a prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this in the future: There is a similar topic with more up-to-date and more detailed answers regarding this issue- [Embedding/deploying custom font in .NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007805/embedding-deploying-custom-font-in-net-app/3008351)