# Embedding/deploying custom font in .NET app

Tags: .net, winforms, deployment, fonts

Is there an official way to distribute (deploy) a specific font with a .NET application?

We have a (public domain) "LED font" that prints numbers with the retro LED instrumentface look. This is a standard True Type or Open Type font like any other except it looks funky.

Obviously for that to work, this font needs to be on the user's machine. But we'd prefer to not force the user to "install our special font into your font folder". We'd prefer to either load a Font object directly from the TTF, or programatically install the font so it's available.

How do applications handle this sort of things? Eg, I notice Adobe XYZ installs various fonts on the system without user intervention. That's what we'd like to do.

EDIT: okay, *ideally*, we'd prefer *not* to install the font directly. We don't want our nifty themed LED font showing up in the user's font dropdown in MS Word. We'd prefer to use this font, but restrict its use or appearance to our app. Any way to do this?

EDIT 2: This is for a WinForms .NET 2.0 app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use a custom font for my custom graphics-library on an asp.net site, but this *should* also work on winform without issues. You just specify the font-file, the font-size and the font-style, and the font-type is returned.

```
public static LoadedFont LoadFont(FileInfo file, int fontSize, FontStyle fontStyle)
{
    var fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    fontCollection.AddFontFile(file.FullName);
    if (fontCollection.Families.Length < 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No font familiy found when loading font");
    }

    var loadedFont = new LoadedFont();
    loadedFont.FontFamily = fontCollection.Families[0];
    loadedFont.Font = new Font(loadedFont.FontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    return loadedFont;
}
```

LoadedFont is a simple struct

```
public struct LoadedFont
{
    public Font Font { get; set; }
    public FontFamily FontFamily { get; set; }
}
```

This is needed to prevent the FontFamily to be GC'ed and the font not working (asp.net, i do not know if it is needed on winform).

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know there *was* a PrivateFontFamily class. That should do it.

Comment: It works. At least with the test font I just tried. Seems this is the exact purpose of those classes. :)

Comment: Why would you need a struct to prevent garbage collection? As long as you hold a reference, it will never be collected right?

Comment: Can this font be used in WPF XAML files or just in code?

Answer (score 4):

For a WPF app you can add it as a resource.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx)

You would just have to set the build action to resource and then reference it as follows:

`<TextBlock FontFamily="./Resources/#Custom Font Name">`

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. I wish like heck I could *use* WPF. Unfortunately this app is straight Winforms.

Comment: Great tip!! But it is not working for me :( I had <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"> and now I am trying to reference by adding seguisym.ttf and then writing <TextBlock FontFamily="./_Resources/#Segoe UI Symbol">. I tried BuildAction: Resource, Embedded Resource and Content but none of them work. The reason for this manual inclusion is that Windows 8 has a newer version of the font with several icons that I need also on clients running Windows 7.